# What data can be collected from scanning cellphones in a specific area and what are ways to scan?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, detection, mobile-phones

I'm interested in scanning cellphones. What are ways to scan cellphones? I know one can detect cellphones with wifi, 3g or bluetooth. What are other ways? And what data can be collected with consensus from the user of the phone and what data without?

Comment: I've heard lasers can scan things. You might try lasers.

Comment: I was at a conference where they gave a demo of an advanced security camera on an LED streetlight that also served as a WiFi hotspot, and they could supposedly track movement of people throughout a city as long as they were carrying a phone with the WiFi turned on. Something about the device's MAC address being constantly transmitted over the network...